# GAE instances switching

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-module

When client logs in to a system, he gets routed to one instance ( or new one created for him ), my first question during using the system on that instance, will he gets switched/routed to another instance ?

If he gets routed, how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to have 'sticky sessions' with GAE.

If your implementation depends on one client 'sticking' to the same instance, then your application is inherently not scalable.

Comment: Just to add to this, *Manual* and *Basic* [scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) do provide some level of instance addressability but it's really just for long-running processes on resident instances. As *koma* says, if you're relying on it for your user-facing requests, your application will not scale.

Comment: Basic scaling is not enabled in Java.

Comment: How can Manual scaling help ? Instances can always spawn and requests can be assigned to those new instances.

Comment: @sami Basic scaling is not currently available in the Java *Development* Server, it is available in production ! Instances in BASIC or MANUAL scaling are addressable at URLs with the form: `http://instance.version.module.app_id.appspot.com`